# Return values of spawned powershell.exe and cmd.exe shells

Tags: windows, powershell, error-handling, cmd, salt-stack

The background here is that I'm using SaltStack on Windows, and because it's Windows support is patchy I have to get it to run a lot of batch and powershell scripts or commands.

Salt is a Python program, so it spawns instances of powershell.exe and cmd.exe and either passes them the explicit code to run, or a path to a file. In its simplest model, Salt uses the return value of the cmd.exe or powershell.exe process to decide if the task succeeded or failed.

What I'm wondering is, what controls the return value in each case? Is it just the exit code of the last command executed by the shell, unless you explicitly call "**exit**" with a return code?

I know in Powershell you have **$?** and **$lastexitcode**, which have different uses. I'm wondering whether this complicates things or not. Is the return code of the powershell.exe different depending on whether the last command executed is a PowerShell function or Cmdlet, or a WIN32 binary?

Are the rules the same for a script file vs. an explicit command?

i.e.

```
PowerShell -Command Write-Host "Foo"
```

vs.

```
PowerShell -File script.ps1

cmd /c echo foo
```

vs.

```
cmd /c test.bat
```

Perhaps it's really simple, but I've seen some examples around like:-

- `cmd /c do_something & exit %ERRORLEVEL%`
- `echo do_something; exit $lastexitcode | powershell -command -`

I'd love to know what the catches are to getting this error handling correct.

Comment: There are no rules for CMD. It's a case by case basis (depending on the program cmd is running). So Dos commands, even if now Windows' commands, support the documented Dos errorlevels (which have nothing to do with Dos error codes). Program's written for Windows depend on the technology used. See ExitProcess

Ends the calling process and all its threads.


VOID WINAPI ExitProcess(
  UINT uExitCode
);

Parameters
uExitCode 
[in] The exit code for the process and all threads. 
Return Value
This function does not return a value.

Comment: Remarks
Use the GetExitCodeProcess function to retrieve the process's exit value. Use the GetExitCodeThread function to retrieve a thread's exit value.

Exiting a process causes the following:


All of the object handles opened by the process are closed. 
All of the threads in the process, except the calling thread, terminate their execution. The entry-point functions of all loaded dynamic-link libraries (DLLs) are called with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH. After all attached DLLs have executed any process termination code, this function terminates the current process, including the calling thread.

Comment: The state of the process object becomes signaled, satisfying any threads that had been waiting for the process to terminate. 
The states of all threads of the process become signaled, satisfying any threads that had been waiting for the threads to terminate. 
The termination status of the process changes from STILL_ACTIVE to the exit value of the process.